# How To Measure The Average Response Time On A Sharepoint SiteCollection Programaticly In C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to create a widget for Sharepoint that will show the average response time of a site collection.  I have looked through the API and haven't been able to find anything.  Does anyone know of an API call at either the SPWeb or SPSite level that will give me the average response time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you could accomplish your purpose using some combination of the following two links.

[SharePoint Web Analytics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/03/21/introducing-web-analytics-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) does not quite have the information you are looking for, but it does come equipped with quite a lot of information relating to the usage of your site. This would allow you to (even without looking at average response times) speed up only the pages which are being used most often. Speeding up those pages would have the most dramatic effect on the average speed anyway. (usually).

[LogParser and IISLogs](https://serverfault.com/questions/132892/using-logparser-to-generate-average-response-time-graph) will allow you to generate some reports on response time on the site. However, I am not very familiar with Log Parser, and I don't believe this is something you'd be able to do in real time.
The top answer shows you how to create the graphs, and the second answer shows how to create them on the fly, but not without some effort on your part.

Using a combination of those two answers, you might be able to generate nightly reports (or hourly, whatever your SLA is) and upload them to SharePoint.

Comment: I appreciate it.  I looked at those and they are really good.  I am actually looking for a way to get it programmaticly through C# I am building a custom web part that would need to call from the API.  If there is no way to get it from the API, then I could definately use those as an alternative to the web part.

Comment: @Algorhythm SharePoint does not track that. There are numberous 3rd party tools that will (Intlock is the first one I can think of), but it is definitely not an OOTB SharePoint capability.

Comment: I got it!  Thanks, I will definitely consider using one of those tools.  Thank you very much, DevinB.